# Storing some special characters in SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
update Qtable 
set Q1 = ' If the alternative 
            hypothesis is as  Ha : µ ≠µ0   ;
where QID = '856'
```

`Q1` is of datatype `nvarchar(max)`.

Now that I update in the database and see that instead of  `Ha : µ ≠µ0`, I get

```
Ha : µ ?µ0
```

Not sure why the update statement replaces  ≠ with ? I understand its a special character but what settings should be applied to preserve the value?

Comment: If you want to use **Unicode** based string literals (and "preserve" those special characters), you **must** prefix them with a `N` - `set Q1 = N'.......'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure that you prefix Unicode string literals with an N prefix.
Like this:

```
 update Qtable set Q1=' If the alternative 
 hypothesis is as  Ha :'+ N'µ ≠µ0'   ;
    where QID='856'
```

**QUERY 1:** (OLD Query's String)

```
SELECT 'If the alternative 
 hypothesis is as  Ha:µ ≠µ0';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
If the alternative hypothesis is as Ha:µ ?µ0
```

**QUERY 2:** (NEW Query's String)

```
 SELECT 'If the alternative 
 hypothesis is as  Ha:' + N'µ ≠µ0';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
If the alternative hypothesis is as Ha:µ ≠µ0
```

FOR DEMO Check the below link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/adfb7/1

If you are not using NVARCHAR then you will get your `not equal character` replaced by some other character.

> Nvarchar stores UNICODE data. If you have requirements to store
> UNICODE or multilingual data, nvarchar is the choice. Varchar stores
> ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use.

Comment: well i am using nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 1):

Use this statement:

```
update Qtable 
set Q1 = N'If the alternative hypothesis is as  Ha : µ ≠µ0' 
where QID = '856'
```